# Extend array size

Tags: java

I'm trying to extend my array length with this logic, but I'm still having outOfBounds exception.. any idea or comment help. It seems like my logic is not right
any other way to do this will be great.. or any change to this is is fine to

```
public Student[] createNewArray(Student[] studentListArray){

        for(int i = 0; i < studentListArray.length; i++) {
            if (numberOfStudents == studentListArray.length) {
                newStudentListArray = new Student[studentListArray.length * 2];
                 newStudentListArray = studentListArray;
            }

        }
        return newStudentListArray;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem:
The line below creates a new array with a length twice as long as the original, and then assigns it to the newStudentListArray variable:

```
newStudentListArray = new Student[studentListArray.length * 2];  // Line A
```

The line below then proceeds to discard the previously created unused object and simply assigns the original array to the same variable:

```
newStudentListArray = studentListArray;  // Line B
```

So line B above completely nullifies the word done on Line A.

Solution: Don't do that second line -- don't discard your newly created array. Instead use System.arraycopy to copy data from the original array into your new array. For example

```
newStudentListArray = new Student[studentListArray.length * 2];  // Line A
System.arraycopy(studentListArray, 0, newStudentListArray, 0, 
      studentListArray.length);
```

Comment: thank you, I'm going to try it and see .. i hope it will help

Comment: I understand your logic but.. It's not working for me..Maybe I need to check on other stuff.

Comment: @Semm: "not working" tells us little that would allow us to understand what is going on. Please elaborate. Have you tested the before and after arrays to see what they contain?

Comment: Well, I have the array in the StudentList class, there is GUI which  is displaying all the student instance in JTable.. I'm also trying to call createNewArray()

Comment: public void addStudent (Student collegeStud) {
  studentListArray[numberOfStudents++]= new Student(collegeStud.getFirstName(), collegeStud.getLastName(),
   collegeStud.getStudentId(), collegeStud.getMajor(),collegeStud.getBalance());
 }//this is my addStudent method. do you this i should do something here with the new array?